# proving an $H$ matrix is unitary and showing it's a reflection

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality

i have a problem in this question and can't solve it.

a) $0\ne w\in C^n$ is a column vector.find an neccesary and sufficient rule for w so the matrix $H=I-2ww^*$ will be unitary.

b) show that in this case H is a reflaction matrix to ${w}^\bot$(i.e show that Hw=-w and Hv=v for every $v \in {w}^\bot$.

what i did:

a)for a matrix to be unitary, it needs to follow $U^*U=UU^*=I$, so i tried to look for H so that $H^*H=HH^*=I$ where the column vector $w=\begin{pmatrix}z_1\\ ..\\ z_n\end{pmatrix}$ would become $w^*=(\overline{z_1},...,\overline{z_2})$, but couldn't find a definite and sufficient term for H to be unitary.

b)didn't know how to approach it since i couldn't prove that H is unitary.

don't know how to solve it, especially b.

thank you very much.

Comment: What's $H^*$, using the definition of $H$?

Comment: sorry i wasn't near thecomputer much. since $H=I-2ww*$, i believe thatwhat we are looking for is w*w=1 (so it will be unitary) (this if for a).since nowi can understand  how Hw=-w(because it's complex, but i don't know how to show Hv=v (for every $e \in w ^\bot$). don't know how to continue from there

Comment: I don't understand. Why would $w^*w$ equal $1$? You also didn't answer my question. If $H$ equals $I-2ww^*$, what does $H^*$ equal?

Comment: sorry, what i meant was $w^*w'=w'^*w=1$. anyways i solved it s thank you very much